# pandas date_range does not exclude holidays

Tags: python, pandas, date-range

I have been trying to exclude a set of dates from my pandas bdate_range result but for some reason they keep on appearing.

I was following the notes within here https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.bdate_range.html, ie apply bdate_range and also freq='C' .  I thought that my exclude from list has been set up incorrectly, but am not seeing any errors thrown out when the script is run.

Sample code is below.   Is anyone able to see what I have done wrong?   would prefer the bdate_range to work instead of placing in some sort of workaround

```
import pandas as pd  
import datetime

exclude = [pd.datetime(2020, 1, 7), pd.datetime(2020, 1, 27)]

pd.bdate_range('2020/1/1','2020/1/31',freq='C',  holidays=exclude, )
```

Result still includes the 7th and the 27th that I am attempting to exclude out

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-06',
               '2020-01-07', '2020-01-08', '2020-01-09', '2020-01-10',
               '2020-01-13', '2020-01-14', '2020-01-15', '2020-01-16',
               '2020-01-17', '2020-01-20', '2020-01-21', '2020-01-22',
               '2020-01-23', '2020-01-24', '2020-01-27', '2020-01-28',
               '2020-01-29', '2020-01-30', '2020-01-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='C')
```

[image: screenshot of result]

Have also tried using from datetime as suggested, but same result

[image: using from datetime]

Comment: I get the datetime warning, but my environment pandas1.2.5 Colab environment pandas1.1.5 and the latest version 1.3.3 do not show the 7th and 27th. What is the version you are using?

Comment: thanks, I just had a look and have an older version of pandas.  will update to the latest version and see if it works

Comment: just managed to update the package and its all working now.  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of
`import datetime`
do
`from datetime import datetime`
and instead of
`exclude = [pd.datetime(2020, 1, 7), pd.datetime(2020, 1, 27)]`
do
`exclude = [datetime(2020, 1, 7), datetime(2020, 1, 27)]`

Comment: thanks, tried this as well but same result.   updated my question to reflect the same

Comment: Most likely you have an outdated pandas version. I am using the 1.1.5 version (colab) and it seems to work.

Comment: thanks, I needed to update the library and also change the code as you have shown above to get it to work on my side

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're executing the same thing you're sharing with us here? I just ran your code and it seems to exclude the dates you mention:

```py
DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-06',
               '2020-01-08', '2020-01-09', '2020-01-10', '2020-01-13',
               '2020-01-14', '2020-01-15', '2020-01-16', '2020-01-17',
               '2020-01-20', '2020-01-21', '2020-01-22', '2020-01-23',
               '2020-01-24', '2020-01-28', '2020-01-29', '2020-01-30',
               '2020-01-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='C')
```

In case you get the deprecation warning, don't use `pd.datetime` but rather import it from its own library, using `from datetime import datetime`.

Comment: yep, I am running it via jupyter/ python 3.  have edited the question to show the screenshot of my output